# What is the correct bayesian formulation for the zero-truncated Poisson lognormal model?

Tags: bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian, ecology, stan

In ecology we use compound distributions to describe species-abundance data. One example is the Poisson Lognormal (PLN) distribution which is a Poisson distribution with rate parameter $\lambda$ that follows a lognormal PDF $f(\lambda;\mu,\sigma)$. The total probability of an observation (count) $x$ is then given by:
$$ p(x;\mu,\sigma) = \int_{\lambda = 0}^{+\infty}{\frac{\lambda^x e^{-\lambda}}{x!} f(\lambda;\mu,\sigma) d\lambda} $$
We can't observe zeroes so, we work with a truncated distribution to then construct a likelihood function and use the MLE frequentist estimator to obtain point estimates of $\mu$ and $\sigma$. The truncated PLN distribution is:
$$ p_{T}(x;\mu,\sigma) = \frac{p(x;\mu,\sigma)}{p(x>0;\mu,\sigma)} = \frac{p(x;\mu,\sigma)}{1-p(0;\mu,\sigma)} $$
The conditioning is done based on the total probability (the total probability of $x>0$) not on the conditional probability of $x>0$ (conditioned on a known value of $\lambda$). How can I formulate this model in Bayesian? I would like to use Stan to sample from the posterior $p(\mu,\sigma|\mathbf{x})$ without defining a new distribution.

Comment: First things first: In order to compute a posterior for $\mu$ and $\sigma$, you need a prior for $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

Answer (score 1):

[Stan natively supports truncated distributions](https://mc-stan.org/docs/2_29/stan-users-guide/truncated-data.html) such that you can express the zero truncated likelihood $P(x|\lambda)$ with a sampling statement like this: `x ~ poisson(lambda) T[1,];`.

The Poisson Lognormal (PLN) model that you described can be expressed such that there is a different Poisson rate parameter $\lambda_i$ corresponding to each observation $x_i$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
log(\lambda_i) \sim & \ \mathrm{Normal}(\mu, \sigma) \\
x_i \sim  & \ \mathrm{ZeroTruncatedPoisson}(\lambda_i) \\
\end{aligned}
$$

We also need to define priors on the model parameters $\mu, \sigma$. In practice, we usually have some information specifying a reasonable range for model parameters to specify an informative prior. However, in the absence of any prior information, we can specify [uninformative priors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability#Uninformative_priors) on these parameters. For normal distribution parameters, we can use the improper [Jeffrey's prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeffreys_prior#Gaussian_distribution_with_standard_deviation_parameter):
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mu \sim & \ \mathrm{Uniform}(-\infty, +\infty) \\
log(\sigma) \sim & \ \mathrm{Uniform}(-\infty, +\infty) \\
\end{aligned}
$$

We can express this model in a Stan program, without defining any custom distributions, as follows:

```
data {
  int<lower=0> N;    // number of observations
  int<lower=1> x[N]; // observations
}
parameters {
  real mu;
  real log_sigma;
  vector[N] log_lambda;
}
transformed parameters {
  vector[N] lambda = exp(log_lambda);
  real sigma = exp(log_sigma);
}
model {
  // implicit uninformative improper uniform priors on `mu` and `log_sigma`

  // lognormal prior on lambda
  log_lambda ~ normal(mu, sigma);

  for (i in 1:N) {
    // zero-truncated poisson likelihood for x
    x[i] ~ poisson(lambda[i]) T[1,];
  }
}
```

Then, using this Stan model, we can sample from the posterior distribution $P(\mu, \sigma|x)$. Here's an example where the "true" values are $\mu=1.5, \sigma=0.75$. The range samples from the posterior distribution appear to overlap well with the "true" values in this case.

```py
import pystan
import scipy.stats
import seaborn as sns

N = 200
mu = 1.5
sigma = 0.75
lambda_ = np.exp(np.random.normal(size=N) * sigma + mu)
x = scipy.stats.poisson.rvs(lambda_)
x = x[x > 0]

data = dict(N=len(x), x=x)

model = pystan.StanModel(model_code=MODEL_CODE)
samples = model.sampling(data=data)

df = samples.to_dataframe()
sns.pairplot(df[["mu", "sigma"]], plot_kws=dict(alpha=0.05))
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't the truncation order different in the answer compared to the question? Is a truncated Poisson with a lognormal mixing distribution really equivalent to a truncated Poisson-lognormal?

Comment: I agree with @ebbhead.  This answer implements a different model with truncation happening before rather than after mixing.

Comment: With truncation happening before mixing, the pmf becomes 
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{p(x;\lambda)}{1-p(0;\lambda)}f(\lambda;\mu,\sigma)d\lambda
$$ 
whereas with truncation after mixing, the pmf becomes 
$$
\frac{\int_0^\infty p(x;\lambda)f(\lambda;\mu,\sigma)d\lambda}{1-\int_0^\infty p(0;\lambda)f(\lambda;\mu,\sigma)d\lambda}.
$$

Comment: Is it only possible to implement the truncation using the 1D integrator? Is there no Bayesian (simple) methods to do this "total" truncation?